# How to plot a chart so it adds to the value of previous value instead of plotting it over a zero line

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

In this code i have ploted `pct_day`. Since the value does not increase like it would in a stock value, is it possible to plot this data where the current value which is to be plotted is added to the previous value and that data is plotted. This way the line graph would increase over time as opposed to the image below where the chart is plotted over a zero line?

```
High    Low Open    Close   Volume  Adj Close   year    pct_day
month   day                             
1   2   794.913004  779.509998  788.783002  789.163007  6.372860e+08    789.163007  1997.400000 0.002211
3   833.470005  818.124662  823.937345  828.889339  9.985193e+08    828.889339  1997.866667 0.004160
4   863.153573  849.154299  858.737861  853.571429  1.042729e+09    853.571429  1997.714286 -0.003345
5   900.455715  888.571429  895.716426  894.472137  1.022023e+09    894.472137  1998.357143 -0.001216
6   847.453076  837.161537  840.123847  844.383843  8.889831e+08    844.383843  1998.076923 0.003679
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
12  27  909.735997  900.942000  905.528664  904.734009  7.485793e+08    904.734009  1998.133333 -0.000308
28  946.635010  940.440016  942.995721  944.127147  7.552150e+08    944.127147  1998.071429 0.001251
29  950.723837  941.625390  944.760775  947.200773  6.830400e+08    947.200773  1998.076923 0.002899
30  891.501671  883.954989  887.031665  887.819181  6.010675e+08    887.819181  1997.833333 0.001844
31  918.943857  910.320763  916.251549  913.786154  6.879523e+08    913.786154  1997.923077 -0.002772
363 rows × 8 columns
```

in Jupyter notebook as shows below:
[image: Chart Picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the cumulative sum of the column `pct_day`. First, create a new column where you compute that value by means of numpy [cumsum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html)

```
pct_value_list = df['pct_value'].tolist()
pct_value_cumsum = list(np.cumsum(pct_value_list))
df['pct_value_cumsum'] = pct_value_cumsum
```

After that you can plot by `df.plot(y='pct_value_cumsum')`

Comment: I used the following command `df['pct_day]'.cumsum(axis=0)` but i got `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`

Comment: because there is an error in your code. You have the apex (') out of the square bracket. It should be inside.

Comment: Thanks i did change that `df['pct_day'].cumsum(axis=0)` but got the this error instead `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`